# Как собрать value у всех динамически созданных Input, React-Select

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hook, usestate

[image: Пример вывода кода без контроля состояний Input]

Делается запрос на БД, динамически создаются Input и React-Select(Библиотека).
Проблема:

1. Как создать собственное состояние у каждого Input и React-Select(Их может быть разное кол-во)
2. Как получать значение из этих Input и React-Select

[image: Пример кода]

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Если у вас все это находится в форме и у этих полей есть `name`, вы можете воспользоваться стандартным методом получения значений у формы.

Comment: Дополните вопрос кодом компонентов, а так же, где вы хотите собрать данные со всех input? В родительском компоненте?